# how can i get response after saving in Mongodb with NODEJS

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

By saving data from the postman I want to get a response from MongoDB include newly created document

### Codes

```
async save(req, res){

        const {score, multiplier, level} = req.body;
        const scores =  new Result({score, multiplier, level});
        const savedRes = await scores.save().then(resp=>{
            return resp
                .sendStatus(200)
                .send({
                message:'new record is saved',
                data: savedRes
 
            })
        }).catch(error=>res.sendStatus(500).send(error))
    }
```

### mongo configuration

```
const app = express()
 mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL,{
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
 })
 const con= mongoose.connection
try{
    con.on('open',() => console.log('db connected'))
} catch(error){
     console.log(error)
}
 app.use(cors({origin:"*"}))
```

### Actual result

- Document is created in MongoDB Atlas with `internal server error`  in `postman` reponse body along with `(node:96318) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client` in vscode terminal

### Expected result

```
{
message: 'new record is saved',
data: {
    level: 1,
    multiplier:8
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

From the [documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/5x/api.html#res.sendStatus), `res.sendStatus(..)` does:

> Sets the response HTTP status code to statusCode and sends the
> registered status message as the text response body. If an unknown
> status code is specified, the response body will just be the code
> number.

So it already sends a response and you try to send a response afterwards through `res.send(..)`. You should only *set* the status through `res.status(<statusCode>)`. But since the default status-code is `200`, you can simply do:

```
const {score, multiplier, level} = req.body;
const scores =  new Result({score, multiplier, level});
const savedRes = await scores.save();
res.send({ message:'new record is saved', data: savedRes });
```

Comment: @Janvier: any feedback? Please accept the answer if it solved your question!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `res.sendStatus` and `res.send` at a same time. You can use `res.status(200).json({sample : "sample"})` to specify response status code and response body.

```
async save(req, res){
const {score, multiplier, level} = req.body;
const scores =  new Result({score, multiplier, level});
try{
const savedRes = await scores.save();
res.status(200).json({ message:'new record is saved', data: savedRes });
}catch(err){
res.status(500).json({
Message:"Internal Server Error",
Info: err
})
}
}
```